# ssh connection timed out

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, ssh, macosx

I just started to experiment with ssh and port forwarding. I use ubuntu to ssh into my iMac. The iMac says to use `ssh user1@host` and that works fine when I am using the same network. However, when I connect to my Ubuntu to another network, say at work, and try to ssh into my iMac with `ssh -v -v -v user1@host -p 22` I get the following output:

`debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
 debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
 debug1: Connect to address user1@host port 22: Connection timed out`

I setup my router to forward port 22 to my iMac's ip address--I'm not sure if my ISP is blocking this port, I still need to check this. My router is Netgear Nighthawk R7800 AC2600. Is there anything I need to setup in Ubuntu, in the ssh_config file, to make this connection work?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [canyouseeme.org](http://canyouseeme.org) to check if your ISP is blocking SSH.

I would also check that your iMac is getting a static IP address - otherwise, it'll change, meaning the port forward you set up will become obsolete.

I wanted to add that opening up SSH as you describe is very dangerous. You should use *something* to block abuse. For example, right now, I have a web server with SSH open, running fail2ban.

[fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) works by routing IP addresses to 0.0.0.0 in iptables.
I've configured it so that if you get the password wrong twice, it blocks your IP address for a long time. The incorrect attempts must be within 24 hours of each other.

I just ran `sudo iptables -L -n | grep -c 0.0.0.0` which counts how many IP addresses are blocked right now. It returned `356`, and this is on a site which barely has any visitors.

If you're opening up ports through your firewall to your home PC, bots are going to find it and break in. I don't know how you go about installing this sort of a thing in macOS, but I'd highly recommend doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll look into fail2ban and use canyouseeme.org. I'll report back tonight.

Comment: I ended up fixing the issue. I was using the incorrect ip address when I was ssh'ing into my router. I was originally using the ip address my iMac told me to use under Remote Login.  This worked when I was on the same network but not when I was on another network. I had to use the router ip address found on the router setup page. I'll leave this here since it may help someone. Now I need to find out how to configure fail2ban on Mac OS X 10.13. There seems to be very little new documentation.